# Check if Dialog is already open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, toggle, react-leaflet

I'm working on application where I'm displaying a map & multiple different locations with markers. These markers can be clicked in order to open simple dialog, which shows some information about that specific location. Here is code sample:

*Mapping through array of locations & calling the function on each marker.*

```
      {markers && (
    <>
      {markers.map((marker, idx) => (
        <MarkerDialog key={idx} marker={marker} />
      ))}
    </>
  )}
```

*Adding dialog to marker.*

```
const MarkerDialog = ({ marker }) => {
const [dialog, setDialog] = useState(false);

const handleClickOpen = () => {
setDialog(true);
};

const handleClose = () => {
setDialog(false);
};

const handleMarkerClick = (e, marker) => {
if (dialog) {
  handleClose();
} else {
  handleClickOpen();
}
};

return (
<div>
  <Marker
    position={marker.location}
    icon={status(marker)}
    eventHandlers={{
      click: handleMarkerClick,
    }}
  />

  {dialog && (
    <Dialog
      marker={marker}
      dialog={dialog}
      handleClose={handleClose}
    />
  )}
</div>
);
};

export default MarkerDialog;
```

This creates a problem if you click on multiple markers. In that case the dialogs stack on top of each other, because application never closes previous dialog.

If I click on marker and dialog opens, and then I'll go and click on another marker, I would like that previous dialog closes. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lift the state up and maintain a selected index for the click of the marker.

**MarkerDialog**

```
const MarkerDialog = ({ marker,  handleMarkerClick, handleClose,dialog }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Marker
        position={marker.location}
        icon={status(marker)}
        eventHandlers={{
          click: handleMarkerClick
        }}
      />

      {dialog && (
        <Dialog marker={marker} dialog={dialog} handleClose={handleClose} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MarkerDialog;
```

**Parent**

```
const [selectedMarkerIndex, setSelectedMarkerIndex] = useState(null);

const handleClose = () => {
  setSelectedMarkerIndex(-1)
};

const handleMarkerClick = (e, marker,index) => {
  /* Do stuff with e and marker */
  setSelectedMarkerIndex(index)
};

{
  markers && (
    <>
      {markers.map((marker, idx) => (
        <MarkerDialog
          key={idx}
          marker={marker}
          handleMarkerClick={(e, marker) => handleMarkerClick(e, marker, idx)}
          handleClose={handleClose}
          dialog={idx === selectedMarkerIndex}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```